# How to create a directory shortcut to a directory outside of myfolders in SASUniversityEdition

Tags: sas

How do I get SAS studio to shortcut to a directory outside of 
SASUniversityEdition myfolders on my pc? 
The software will not allow me to do it?
There is a problem entering the path name?
It is not clear what that should be.

Original Data to be input is in c:\mm\data and mmdata must be a shared folder in SASUniversityEdition and have a folder shortcut to c:\mm\data

```
SAS CODE:
data mm; 
infile "/folders/myshortcuts/mmdata/myfile.txt"; 
input ...
run;
```

Thank you.  MM

Comment: Doesn't look much like a programming problem, but in any case at a minimum show what you tried and explain how it did not work.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: No error. The software refuses to allow me to enter path. I am investigating the settings in oracle VM and SAS U but I don't have a clue as to what to change. I am using windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Open your VM application (Oracle Virtual Box most likely)

*You may need to shut down the VM, I can't recall if you need it running or off to set up a shared path*

Add a shared folder to MMData
Ensure it's set to automount

Restart the VM
Start up SAS UE

It should be available now.

This is most definitely possible, I've done it several times.